# App is working fine but when app starts suddenly shows up this screen and disappear

Tags: flutter, dart

I think problem is cause by this following function which supposed to change background of the function.How can I solve this.

```
_decidebg(){
   if(_counter==0){
     return AssetImage("assets/1.jpg");
   }
   else if(_counter<3){
     return AssetImage("assets/2.jpg");
   }
   else if(_counter<=6){
     return AssetImage("assets/3.jpg");
   }
   else{
     return AssetImage("assets/4.jpeg");
   }
 }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The problem is with variable _counter. It is not available for like few miliseconds and it is causing a problem. How do you derive this ? Do you read something from shared prefs ?

Comment: Yeah it reads stored counter value in the disk..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are deriving the value after reading something from the disk. And it takes a few miliseconds to read from the disk. By that time, the value for variable _counter remains null and it shows the red screen then.

To solve the issue, initialise _counter with value say -1 (or whatever works with the logic). And wrap the assignment in setState(). So, something like :

From :

```
_counter = await _______ ;
```

To :

```
int _counter = -1;
...
...
setState() => _counter = await _______ ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because the variable `_counter` is `null`.

You can solve this by given a default value to the `_counter` variable.

I hope this answers. your question.